# How can I change the colour of the line highlighted with the 'cursorline' option?

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I can highlight the current line like this `:set cursorline`, which underlines the current line.

[image]

However I would like to highlight the entire line in a lighter color. How can I achieve this look?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [`:help cursorline`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cursorline%27), the highlight label is `CursorLine`. So you can try:

```
:highlight CursorLine ctermbg=LightBlue
```

See `:help highlight-cterm` for more options.

Experiment with the colours to see which suits you.

Comment: The command works and I want to put it in my .vimrc. So I added this `set highlight cursorline ctermbg=LightBlue` and I get this `E518: Unknown option: ctermbg=LightBlue`

Comment: @Vader try without the set. As in `set cursorline` on one line and the command in my answer on another line.

Comment: That removes the Error, but it still not showing up. Anyway you answered my original questions, so thanks.

Comment: @Vader Did you enable the 256 colors option? Your `.vimrc` should have a line like `set t_Co=256`.

Answer (score 1):

In Vim, to achieve what you want, you have to do the following:

Edit your `vimrc` and add these lines:

```
set cursorline
highlight CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=238
```